# How to replace comma with a space in the string - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove comma:

Current value as : `C,A` `D,` `,B` `D,`
this values coming from DB as above.

Here we will get our response as `C,A` means i selected Answer First and Second Here value in `,B` means First option not selected, second option is selected.

when displaying in UI i do not want display as `C,A` `D,` `,B` `D,`
I want to Display as `C,A` `D,` `B` `D,` (Removing comma only before B).
as I used `r = r.replace(/,/g , " ");`

than it is removing all comma like `C A` `D` `B` `D`

I Want Exactly `C,A`  `D,` `B` `D,`

Comment: Could you please give a better explanation of what you want? - I've given an answer but i'm not 100% sure it's what you want.

Comment: Could you format the question so that it is some way readable. Normally I would do this for you, but I'm struggling to understand what should and should not be included as part of your input string.

Answer (score 2):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
var myStr = "'C,A' 'D,' ',B' 'D'";
var i = myStr.search(/[^A-Z],/g);
myStr = myStr.replaceAt(i+1, ' ');
console.log(myStr);
```

Comment: No yaar " 'C,A', 'D', ',B',  ", there three are separate pairs, after one pair comma is need, but withing pair when student selected second option means first option is nothing na ex : 'C,A',  ' D,_,'  ,  '_, B'.

Comment: Questions Missed : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Your Response : - - - C,A - - - D ,B - 
Tolerance :        NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: Try my edit to the answer, this removes couples starting with a comma.

Comment: This is fine, but when apply this logic, when it read B after that all columns not showing. WE trying to remove from DB only. Thanks.